# django model _meta.get_fields() just datettime fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-modeladmin

I have want gather just fieldname type is datetime by

```
_meta.get_fields()
```

Model.py :

```
class testmodel (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    field = models.CharField('field', max_length=50, choices=(), default=None)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    complete_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

admin.py :

```
all_fields = [f.name for f in testmodel._meta.fields]

class myform(forms.ModelForm):
field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=all_fields)
name = forms.TextInput()

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   fields = ('name', 'field',)
   list_display = ('name', 'field',)
   form = myform

admin.site.register(testmodel,MyModelAdmin)
```

what is solution for this ?

Comment: I can see only two fields using the `DateTimeField`. Is that hard to define it yourself?

Comment: it will be dynamic, May user defined many model by themselves, this is choice filed filled scan all models and find datetime field in each model for set Rule calculation based on datetimefield and operator from User ( SLA Calculation in Workflows )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ***list comprehension*** as

```
from django.db.models import DateTimeField

datetime_model_fields = [field for field in MyModelClass._meta.get_fields() if isinstance(field, DateTimeField)]
```

Comment: Also I Add this for using in Choice field                                                  
      datetime_model_fields = list(zip(datetime_model_fields, datetime_model_fields))